# What's the difference between two gin modes, debug and release?

Tags: go

I mean the different modes of gin, which is the http framework of Golang, not of the VS IDE.

Answer (score 10):

In release mode debug printing will not be as explained [on this link](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/3d44ff82a1fe39b5991f292369eed0d6abf2a430/debug.go).

```golang
func debugPrint(format string, values ...interface{}) {
    if IsDebugging() {
        if !strings.HasSuffix(format, "\n") {
            format += "\n"
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "[GIN-debug] "+format, values...)
    }
}
```